# Mailgun::CommunicationError via nginx '301 Moved Permanently' error

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, http-status-code-301, mailgun

I have a Ruby web app that sends email via Mailgun.

My Mailgun account & gem are properly set up and I can send emails manually (via curl, for instance).

The API key and the API base URL (https sandbox domain) are stored in environment variables.

When I attempt to send emails from the app like this:

```
  def initialize(mailer: nil)
    @mailer = mailer || Mailgun::Client.new(ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'])
  end
```

then:

```
  def call(user)
    mailer.send_message(ENV['MAILGUN_SANDBOX'], {from: '...',
        to: user.email,
        subject: '...',
        text: "..."})
  end
```

When I run the app with Sinatra via localhost:xxxx, I get a Mailgun::CommunicationError at /.../... 301 Moved Permanently: ... nginx pointing to this line:

```
mailer.send_message(ENV['MAILGUN_SANDBOX'], ...
```

Any idea why that happens? I've researched the issue for hours but couldn't find a clue on what to do next.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. If you have already fixed this then hopefully this can help someone else.

I switched over to message builder for ease of use and being able to `render` my html but I'm pretty sure it will still send with the format you have setup with `:text`

When I switched over to the proper `domain` in the `.env` file I believe it solved my issue. You'll need 2 different domains to use Mailgun. The first is the full domain for your sandbox. `ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']` it is the sandbox domain with the full `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXXxxxXXXXXX.mailgun.org` to send most of the mail formats.

You'll also need the last half of the full domain to send messages. That's just the `sandboxXXXXxxxXXXXXX.mailgun.org` which is passed into the `MessageBuilder` or other message `.send_message` method. When I had them mixed up or both the same I kept on getting this error. When I switched over to separate the two in my `development.rb` and `some_mailer.rb` is when I could send the mail without a problem.

Below is my file setup, for reference. I'm pretty new to all of this but this is how I'm setup and it's working for me so hopefully it helps.

```
# .env 
MAILGUN_DOMAIN='https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXXxxxXXXXXX.mailgun.org'
MAILGUN_SEND_DOMAIN='sandboxXXXXxxxXXXXXX.mailgun.org'

# development.rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :authentication => :plain,
  :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']",
  :user_name => "ENV['MAILGUN_USERNAME']",
  :password => "ENV['MAILGUN_PASSWORD']"
}


# some_mailer.rb
def some_mail_notification(user)
  @user = user

  mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['MAILGUN_KEY']
  mb_obj = Mailgun::MessageBuilder.new
  mb_obj.from "email@testing.com", {'first' => 'Customer', 'last' => 'Support'}
  mb_obj.add_recipient :to, @user.email, { 'first' => @user.first_name, 'last' => @user.last_name }
  mb_obj.subject "Your Recent Purchase on Some Site"
  mb_obj.body_html ("#{render 'some_mail_notification.html.erb'}")
  mg_client.send_message("sandboxXXXXxxxXXXXXX.mailgun.org", mb_obj)
end
```

I left the `send_message` above to the sandbox domain but you can set that as an environment variable in the `.env` file.